# Какие должны стоять знаки препинания в конструкции “что хуже/лучше”: тире, двоеточие или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Какие должны стоять знаки препинания в конструкции “что хуже/лучше”? Пример:

"Что хуже — быть бедным или глупым?"

"Я даже не знаю, что хуже — потерять работу или потерять дом"

Мое внутреннее чутье подсказывает мне, что здесь может стоять тире, но почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современном русском языке двоеточие и тире во многих случаях конкурируют между собой. Общеизвестно, что тире в этой борьбе побеждает, перетягивая на себя всё больше функций, которые раньше были более свойственны двоеточию.

Рассматриваемая конструкция широко распространена в русском языке, и если ограничить статистику наиболее авторитетными источниками, то оба знака в такой конструкции будут представлены примерно на равных (я заметил, что тире попадается чуть чаще). Если Вы много читаете, то Ваша интуиция может быть основана на (неосознаваемом) накопленном опыте, как это чаще всего и бывает с интуицией.

Поскольку именно тире вызывает здесь основные споры, приведу несколько подтверждающих цитат (при желании каждый может нагуглить ещё сотни или тысячи таких же; важно только ограничиваться при этом авторитетными издательствами или авторами).

> Что главнее — хлеб или мясо? (Литературное обозрение, Изд-во "Правда", 1990)
>
> Поэтому как метафизическую следует расценивать постановку вопроса, что важнее — функционирование или развитие, ... (Русское языкознание, Изд-во "Выща школа", 1986)
>
> Что важнее для языка — быть средством общения или быть средством
> воплощения мысли? (Введение в языкознание, Гос. учебно-педагог.
> изд-во, 1953)
>
> Например, если глухие согласные произнсятся напряжённо, а звонкие
> ненапряжённо, то что важнее — звонкость или напряжённость? ("Как язык
> меняется", Бурлак С.А., Москва, Изд-во МЦНМО)
>
> Что важнее — дистрибуционное содержание какого-нибудь признака, т. е.
> место, занимаемое им в семантическом пространстве, или его
> морфологическая форма? (Проблемы структурной лингвистики, Изд-во
> Академии наук СССР, 1972)
>
> ... Искусственность проблемы, что важнее — синтагматика или
> парадигматика, становится очевидной. (Системная типология языков,
> Изд-во "Наука", 2003)
>
> Один уроженец местности Жэнь спросил у Лу-цзы: «Что важнее — ритуал
> или пища?» — «Ритуал важнее», — был ответ. «А что важнее — обладание
> женщиной или ритуал?» — «Ритуал важнее», — снова последовал ответ.
> (Древнекитайский язык, Изд-во "Наука", 1978)
>
> ... Вопрос о том, что появляется раньше в предложно-падежных
> сочетаниях — окончание или предлог. (Становление имени, Мария
> Воейкова, Институт лингвистических исследований)
>
> Что важнее — писать без ошибок или с ошибками, но при этом точно,
> понятно выражать свои мысли? (Русский язык для студентов-нефилологов,
> учебное пособие, 1997)
>
> Теперь уже не спорят о том, что важнее при усвоении орфографии —
> зрение или слух, списывание или диктант. (Методика русского языка для
> школьных педагогических училищ, Просвещение, 1973)
>
> Спрашиваем, что важнее в данных определениях — характеристика солдат с
> разных точек зрения или дополняющие друг друга признаки (Русский язык
> в школе, Учпедгиз., 2003)

**Дополнение.

Пояснение по поводу конфликта двоеточия и тире.**

Н.С. Валгина (надеюсь, её авторитет никто не будет оспаривать) в ["Синтаксисе современно русского языка"](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-060.htm) объясняет, почему правила употребления двоеточия и тире отстают от реальности и требуют уточнений.

> Сопоставление употребления двоеточия и тире в разные
> исторические эпохи очень показательно. В настоящее время выявляется
> тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире.
> Употребление двоеточия сводится к очень конкретным и явно
> немногочисленным случаям, оно закрепляется в позиции перед
> перечислением. В других же случаях, даже когда это поддерживается ныне
> действующими правилами пунктуации См.: Правила русской орфографии и
> пунктуации. - М., 1956., двоеточие практически заменяется тире. В
> современных публикациях часто ставится тире в бессоюзном сложном
> предложении при обозначении причины, пояснения, конкретизации во
> второй части: Не узнать Москвы — она преображена новыми кварталами,
> зданиями, разбежавшимися на запад, север, юг (газ.); Долго плавать не
> приходится — аллигаторы здесь не редкость (журн.); Я взглянул на
> названия — то были труды по гидрографии различных морей (Пауст.).
>
> Тире начинает заменять двоеточие и в бессоюзных предложениях с
> присоединительной частью: Бугаёв поднял голову — в зимней ночи ясно
> был виден правильной формы, наполненный воздухом купол (Ванш.);
> Малинин притронулся рукой — под ватником плечо было теплое, Михнецов
> был жив (Сим.).
>
> Тире вместо двоеточия все чаще ставится и перед перечислением после
> обобщающего слова. Например: Они ничем не «украсили» свой фильм — ни
> песней, ни гитарой, ни вообще музыкой, ни закадровым голосом (газ.); В
> новом цехе организуется массовое производство изделий для
> машиностроения — втулок, стаканов, зубчатых секторов... (газ.).
>
> Встречается тире и в сложноподчиненном предложении, где «по правилам»
> опять-таки должно быть двоеточие, так как в главной части предложения
> есть слова, предупреждающие о последующем разъяснении. Например: Он
> хотел только одного — чтобы окружающие поняли, что его воображения и
> умения радовать хватит на тысячи людей, а не на двух-трех (Пауст.).
>
> **Такое расширенное употребление тире в настоящее время стало настолько
> массовым, что свод правил в данном отношении явно не соответствует
> живому употреблению и нуждается в уточнении.**

Comment: *если ограничить статистику наиболее авторитетными источниками*  вот это особенно авторитетно:  Русское языкознание, Изд-во "Выща школа", 1986

Comment: *Искусственность проблемы, что важнее — синтагматика или парадигматика, становится очевидной.* - а здесь вообще должно быть не тире, а запятая, если по смыслу.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что разбираться в авторитетности издательств — это не то же самое, что разбираться в правилах русского языка.

Comment: Цитаты, которые начинаются с многоточия, приведены не полностью. В гугло-книгах они не копируются и я поленился набирать полностью особо длинные цитаты (но они легко гуглятся).

Comment: Авторитетным источником можно считать автора уровня Розенталя. Издательство здесь вообще не при делах. Розенталь где-то (в "Практической стилистике", кажется, нет возможности сейчас искать) говорит о тенденции замены двоеточия на тире, но там чистая фиксация, в отношении норматиности/допусмтимости такой замены я ничего не помню. А единствееный безусловный случай замены двоеточия на тире связан с нежелательностью использования двух двоеточий в одной фразе  (если только они не при однородных рядах) - см. Екатерина.

Comment: @behemothus Среди авторов приведенных цитат есть и такие лингвисты, что не нам с вами сравнивать уровень их авторитетности с Розенталем. А по поводу отношения к издательствам и по другим вопросам выбора жизненной позиции я спорить не буду — здесь каждый в своём праве.

Comment: *что не нам с вами сравнивать уровень их авторитетности с Розенталем* - это прочему? Не, я не утверждаю, что все авторы - невежды, сама постановка вопроса забавляет. Если вам подали на завтрак тухлое яйцо, вы не вправе судить о компетенции повара? И самого заведения?

Comment: @behemothus Я дополнил ответ пояснениями Валгиной Н.С. о тенденциях вытеснения двоеточия знаком тире. А для обсуждения тухлых яиц найдите себе, пожалуйста, других собеседников :)

Comment: @grizzly, прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, но получается, что **что** - обобщающее слово, а идущие после тире члены предложения - однородные члены?

Comment: @KingCrimson Я бы согласился с такой трактовкой.

Comment: @grizzly, хорошо, спасибо вам большое.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что необходимую паузу (без неё меняется смысл фразы) перед оборотом с *или* может заполнить либо тире, либо двоеточие. Последнее подходит более к перечислению.

> «Меня волновал вопрос, что хуже — понимать, что человеку нужна помощь
> и не сделать ничего, или потерпеть неудачу, попытавшись помочь?» —
> говорил Мунджу на пресс-конференции в Канне.  *[Лариса Юсипова. «За холмами» дьявол не носит Prada // > Известия, 2012.10.25]*

Comment: Во дела... Спрашивающий ставит знаки по интуиции, а отвечающему очевидно, что этот знак должен стоять. Я даже не знаю, что веселее.

Comment: Комментирующий видит слово «должен»?

Comment: *Комментирующий видит слово «должен»?* Я вижу "может заполнить... либо, либо". Хотите меня убедить, что "может, но не должен"?!

Comment: Я утверждаю, что необходимо на письме обозначить паузу.

Comment: Я вас об этом не спрашивал. Я всего лишь отвечал на ваш вопрос, вижу ли я слово "должен". А что там насчет паузы - это вы про интонационное тире изволите говорить? ну тогда это "авторский знак", который отнюдь не является необходимым. Вот если бы тут был явный период - я бы еще соглачился. А так... Я в своем ответе дал ссылку на все случаи использования тире в простых предложениях, найдете что-то подходящие под вашу версии о паузе?

Comment: PS я думаю над вашей цитатой. Пунктуация в ней мне не нравится - ну это ладно. Я не могу понять сакрального смысла всей фразы... Прямой речи, то есть.

Comment: Это полная цитата. Источник искать не хочется. ====  О том, что умирающую девушку не надо было везти в больницу, потому что теперь придется отчитываться за труп.   «Меня волновал вопрос, что хуже — понимать, что человеку нужна помощь и не сделать ничего, или потерпеть неудачу, попытавшись помочь?» — говорил Мунджу на пресс-конференции в Канне. И добавил, что, с его точки зрения, равнодушие тоже можно было бы отнести к списку смертных грехов.

Comment: *Это полная цитата* - я не ставлю это под сомнение. Вопрос в другом. Вы понимаете её смысл? Прямой речи? Я - не очень.  Может, отсюда и тире.

Comment: Ой, понял. Там запятой не хватает после слова "помощь". ))) Без нее - никак.  А после "ничего"  запятая лишняя. Это провал, Штирлиц. На такой *своеобразный* источник ориентироваться... гм... не стоит.

Comment: Полная, т.е. всё, что есть в НКРЯ. Мысль понимаю. Канва эпизода или сценария, изложенная сочинителем. Не уверен, что запятая нужна. http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&startyear=1993&text=lexform&req=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5&api=1.0&mode=paper&env=alpha&nodia=1&endyear=2013&p=2

Comment: *Полная, т.е. всё, что есть в НКРЯ* - да что с того-то? Впрочем, я уже убедился, что корректор ворон считал.  *Мысль понимаю* - именно при такой пунктуации? Объясните мне, неразумному, кто там на ком стоял?  *Не уверен, что запятая нужна* - какая именно?

Answer (score 0):

Мне не удалось добиться от вопрошающего внятного мотива постановки тире.
Полагаю, что его и нет в природе.

Вот все случаи bспользования тире:
[https://therules.ru/dash/]](https://therules.ru/dash/%5D)
в элементарном изложении, дабы дух Розенталя не тревожить.
Ничего подходящего не вижу.

На что обратил внимание, так это на то, что автор две совершенно по-разному построенных фразы объединил в нетно общее.

И если во  втором случае тире еще как-то можно обосновать наличием периода (это "авторский" знак, который ставится не вопреки правилам, но в силу особого авторского понимания этой фразы), то первый вариант можно объяснить только "интуицией". Которая автора подвела.

Я всерьез рассматриваю здесь только двоеточие - на основании того, что дальше идет группа однородных членов, что фактически эквивалентно перечислению.

Впрочем, давно подмечено, что имеется некая тенденция: авторы заменяют законное двоеточие на тире, потому что "так красивше".

И это, кстати, одна из причин, почему я так добивался мотива. был бы малейший мотив - можно было бы как-то принять эту линию.
Впрочем, искать мотивы у автора, полагающего, что большая часть знаков ставится по интуиции - и при этом требующего от остальных обоснования этой своей интуиции... Довольно странно, так скажем.

(+)===

Я не поленился посмотреть в нацкорпусе. на похожие случаи с "что лучше"/"что хуже".

Основная масса - с двоеточием, правда не все авторитетные, есть с явными пунктуационными ошибками в другой части предложения.
При этом всего два примера (не очень убедительных; оба с "что хуже"), где использовано тире.

Ограничусь несколькими примерами.
Полужирный курсив везде мой (b-s).

> Кстати, за незаконное приобретение, хранение, сбыт, передачу,
> перевозку и ношение огнестрельного оружия Уголовный кодекс РФ
> предусматривает наказание в виде лишения свободы сроком до 4 лет.
> ***Что лучше: деньги или тюрьма?***

[ Прощай, оружие! // «Марийская правда» (Йошкар-Ола), 2003.09.01]

> Теперь надо было решать, ***что лучше: звонить и пробовать договориться
> заранее или идти напролом***.

[Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

> Кто знает, ***что лучше: сын, отбывающий срок за хищение, или сын, к
> которому можно приходить только на кладбище***?

[Александра Маринина. Ангелы на льду не выживают. Т. 1 (2014)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

> Он вспомнил давнишний тюремный спор: ***что хуже, что страшнее ― лагерь или тюрьма?***

[В. Т. Шаламов. Колымские рассказы (1954-1961)]
Вот тут тире оправдано наличием периода - раз, а двоеточие уже использовано - два.

> Я не совсем уверен, что хуже: жечь книги или не читать их. [Андрей
> Ранчин.

Несвоевременные мысли: о проектах реформ российского образования «Неприкосновенный запас», 2009]

Короче, мне непонятна эта интуиция. От слова "совсем".

Comment: Почему вы не воспринимаете второй пример как что-то похожее? Если я все правильно понимаю, то в первым предложении **что**  - подлежащее, а **хуже** - сказуемое. Во втором примере **что** выступает союзным словом, играющим роль подлежащего, а **хуже** все еще является сказуемым. Я могу быть и не прав, объясните мне тогда, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы меня неправильно поняли, я не имею в виду, что знаки ставятся по интуиции. На каждый знак существует свое правило, однако многие люди, в т. ч. и я, не задумываются о правилах постановки многих знаков препинания при написании предложения.