# Объясните смысл или пунктуацию в цитате из газеты

Tags: пунктуация

Вопрос возник в связи с обсуждением в [Какие должны стоять знаки препинания в конструкции “что хуже/лучше” - тире, двоеточие или запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461242)

Дано: цитата из нацкорпуса.

> «Меня волновал вопрос, что хуже — понимать, что человеку нужна помощь
> и не сделать ничего, или потерпеть неудачу, попытавшись помочь?» —
> говорил Мунджу на пресс-конференции в Канне.

[Лариса Юсипова. «За холмами» дьявол не носит Prada // > Известия, 2012.10.25]

Задача. ***Поясните смысл фразы в предположении, что знаки стоят правильно.*** Интересует прямая речь, конкретно: альтернатива, рассматриваемая говорящим и оформленная в виде придаточного "что...".

Это для меня принципиально, ибо цитата была приведена как пример использования тире, но если в целом пунктуация ошибочна, то пример этот можно смело списать на неадекватность корректора.

Answer (score 1):

В приведённом предложении, на мой взгляд, действительно есть пунктуационные недочёты. Предлагаю варианты постановки знаков препинания.

***«Меня волновал вопрос, что хуже: понимать, что человеку нужна помощь, и не сделать ничего, (?) или потерпеть неудачу, попытавшись помочь»,*** — говорил Мунджу на пресс-конференции в Канне.

**ЧТО** (хуже)  — **относительное** местоимение, **знак вопроса** убираем. Ставим **запятую**, завершающую придаточное *что человеку нужна помощь*. **Двоеточие** ставим после ЧТО (хуже) перед конструкцией с однородными элементами.

***«Меня волновал вопрос: что хуже  — понимать, что человеку нужна помощь, и не сделать ничего, (?) или потерпеть неудачу, попытавшись помочь?» — говорил Мунджу на пресс-конференции в Канне.***

**ЧТО** (хуже)  — **вопросительное** местоимение, требующее **знака вопроса** в конце предложения. **Двоеточие** ставим по правилу постановки этого знака в БСП (*А именно какой вопрос?*).  **Тире ставим вместо предполагаемого второго двоеточия**. Такая замена вполне допустима.

Меня очень заинтересовала запятоя на месте, обозначенном мной (?). Но это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Я именно так. Это единственный осмысленный вариант правки. К сожалению, мой оппонент не обозначил своего понимания фразы (можете убедиться по ссылке), поэтому пришлось просить "помощь зала", ибо вопрос оказлся принципиальным. Насчет запятой перед "или" - я не вижу для неё мотивов. Возможно, она там появилась, переехав с законного места после "помощи".

Comment: *Тире ставим вместо предполагаемого второго двоеточия. Такая замена вполне допустима.* - Тоже согласен. Я и пример нашел из Шаламова. Опять же по ссылке.

Comment: А зачем вторая запятая (из исходного варианта)? Упрощенно:" _понимать и не сделать_ или _попытаться помочь_" = "первое или второе (хуже)". У корректоров запятая просто стояла не на своем месте.